# Streaming Music Service with a Public API

Tags: c#, api

Back in December I released Elpis, an open source Pandora Radio client... and then Pandora promptly squashed the ability for third party clients like mine to connect to the service without some seriously complicated work-arounds. It still somewhat works, as long as you never skip a song or change the station :P  But I've pretty much ended support of Elpis because it's just not worth playing an ever harder game of cat a mouse...
So... there are a TON of streaming music services out there and I'm trying to figure out if there is at least one that has a decently open API with which I would be able to retrofit Elpis to use that service instead.  I'm guess, due to licensing, the answer is going to be a definite no... but I wanted to at least query the community before giving up?

An no, I'm not talking about something like Last.FM's api that just lets you get the song *info* but something that actually lets you play the music.  I don't really care if there's already a C# API for it... as long as it's got a REST, RPC, etc. web API, I can make it work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Adam, were you able to look into the Spotify API to solve your solution? If so what are your latest results?

Answer (score 0):

Spotify has an [API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/) that allows you to stream music. I've never personally used it, but a colleague of mine was working on a personal project that allowed him to change what was playing on his machine via a web service; accessible from another machine over the network or internet.

Note: I believe you need to have a Pro account to develop with it, though.

Comment: Link is broken, please fix!

Comment: @Stunner Link has now been replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up recording my speaker in c# using a wasapi loopback capture routine. It has a webbrowser control so it knows the title, artist and album. The browser streams the music to my audio output jack, and a separate thread reads the music from my sound card. The only way they could ever protect against that is to stop streaming in the first place.